# Use JavaScript in AJAX response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

there is any way to use javascript in PHP page that i call with AJAX?

i want to build a function that have a source of design. there is 2 places that i need to use this design. one in the PHP page that i call with the AJAX. and one in JavaScript source. i try to think how could i use the same source of the design in these different functions (one in PHP, and enother with JS)

if someone have an another idia how to do this, it can be greate.

**this is my full ajax source:**

```
function ajax(divName, url, generalInfo, info, type) {  
    var xhr;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    var params = "generalInfo="+generalInfo+"&"+infoToTxt(info)+"&divName="+divName;
    xhr.open("POST",url,true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
             document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xhr.send(params);
    return false;
}
```

**this is the PHP page that i call with AJAX:**

```
<?php
echo "<div id='a'> aabbb </div>";
?>

<script language=javascript>
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "sss";
</script>
```

Comment: No. Why would you need to do that anyway? You can just manipulate the element or returned data in the callback function anyway. Also, why not just set the `innerHTML` to `sss` in the first place?

Comment: At the start you set up a variable xmlhttp that you then never use in favour of xhr. This way it'll still fail in older versions of IE.

Comment: @BenM i want to build a function that hava a design. there is 2 places that i need to use this design. one in the PHP page that i call with the AJAX. and one in JavaScript source. i try to think how could i use the same source of the design in these different functions (one in PHP, and enother with JS).

Comment: @Jorg you right. i will change it

Answer (score -1):

No, why would you need that anyway :P

Change

```
<?php
echo "<div id='a'> aabbb </div>";
?>

<script language=javascript>
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "sss";
</script>
```

To

```
<div id='a'>sss</div>
```

Comment: i add to the top of the page what i want to do with this.

Comment: I dont think you know what ajax is for :(